# How to get mouse release coordinates in QGraphicsView

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Hi I'm new to Qt and pyside. I'm trying to get the coordinates of mouse in a QGraphicsView instance. I tried to reimplement my mouseReleaseEvent but wondering how would I actually use this reimplemented function.

In MainWindow class:

```
self.tScn = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
self.graphicsView_2 = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget, self.tScn)
```

In MainConsumer class(derived from MainWindow:

```
def pointSelection(self):
    pos = self.tScn.mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent)
    print(pos)

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
    pos = QMouseEvent.lastScenePos()
    print(pos)
    return pos
```

python gives me this warning:

`AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QMouseEvent' object has no attribute 'lastScenePos`'

I tried couple of different orders and structures but nothing worked and now I am really confused by the relationship between `PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsScene.mouseReleaseEvent(event)`, `PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent.lastScenePos()`, `class PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent([type=None])` and `QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMouseRelease` could somebody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that inherits from QGraphicsScene and has a signal like this

```
class MyGraphicsScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    signalMousePos = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPointF)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyGraphicsScene, self).__init__(parent)
```

and then override the mouseRelease event in this new class

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent):
    pos = QGrapihcsSceneMouseEvent.lastScenePos()
    self.signalMousePos.emit(pos)
```

Then in your MainConsumer class replace

```
self.tScn = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
```

with

```
self.tScn = MyQGraphicsScene()
self.tScn.signalMousePos.connect(self.pointSelection)
```

the pointSelection becomes

```
def pointSelection(self, pos)
    #Whatever you want to do with the position coordinates
```

and mouseReleaseEvent in MainConsumer is no longer necessary

Comment: Thank you so much!! Lol exactly at 11 mins ago I figured out by myself and come back to answer my own question but your explanation is more organized and clear so thanks again!